# Alternate div background color

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, dom, pseudo-class

I have a structure like the following:

```
<div class="wrapper"...>
   <a href="#"...>blah</a>
   <div class="post"...>stuff</div>
</div>
```

And it repeats throughout a dynamic page a few times. I would like to alternate the background colors of the div class "post" with two colors, but CSS's nth-child pseudo class only seems to work with items that are directly sequential.

Is there a way (CSS, Javascript, jQuery, etc.) that I can alternate the div background colors?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

jQuery's :odd and :even selectors are pretty handy:

```
$(".post:even").css("background-color","blue"); 
$(".post:odd").css("background-color","red");
```

HTML:

```
<div class="wrapper">
   <a href="#">blah</a>
   <div class="post">stuff</div>
</div>
<div class="wrapper">
   <a href="#">blah</a>
   <div class="post">stuff</div>
</div>
...
```

http://jsfiddle.net/thomas4g/uaYd9/2/

EDIT:

The non-jQuery, quick JS way:

```
var posts = document.getElementsByClassName("post");
for(var i=0;i<posts.length;i++) {
  posts[i].classList.add(i % 2 === 0 ? "even" : "odd");
  //or
  posts[i].style["background-color"] = i % 2 === 0 ? "blue" : "red";
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I seem to be having trouble with this, though. I have included jQuery, and I used this:

`$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".post:even").css("background-color","blue"); 
  $(".post:odd").css("background-color","red"); 
});`
but it does not work.

Comment: @Rodney which version of jQuery are you including? does the link i posted work for you?

Comment: @Rodney hm, weird. which browser are you using? have you trimmed down your code to only that provided in my answer (to eliminate any possible interferance)?

Comment: I may have conflicting/higher-precedent CSS. I'll review my code and get back to you. Thanks so much!

Comment: Yep, just a CSS conflict. Works great now! Thanks!

Answer (score 7):

the jquery way:

```
$('.post:even').css('background-color','green');
$('.post:odd').css('background-color','red');
```

Answer (score 2):

Typically what I do is assign a css class of "odd" or "even" on the back end.  For example, if the page is dynamically generated in PHP, I'd do something like:

```
for ($i = 0; $i < count($rows); $i++) {
  $css_class = 'wrapper ';  // Elements can have multiple css classes
  $css_class .= $i % 2 == 0 ? 'row_odd' : 'row_even';
  // generate html using class="$css_class"...
}
```

Then define in your class the colors you want the alternating divs to have.

```
.row_odd { background-color: white; }
.row_even { background_color: #e0e0ff; }
```

Comment: Unfortunately, I cannot use PHP on this page. Thanks, though!

Answer (score 1):

Can be done with jquery `:odd` and `:even` selectors quite easily:

```
$(".wrapper div.post:odd").addClass('odd'); 
$(".wrapper div.post:even").addClass('even');
```

http://jsfiddle.net/niklasvh/fULRZ/

Answer (score 1):

```
.post:nth-child(odd)
```

Doesn't work for you?

Comment: Nope. I believe the .post divs would have to be exactly sequential (i.e., no parent divs wrapping them).

Comment: English is my first language.  However, I wasn't implying they were dumb.  Merely trying to clarify the css they used previously that was not working.

I think it was a harmless question perhaps better put in a comment but harmless nonetheless.

Answer (score 0):

```
:even Selector
```

http://api.jquery.com/even-selector/

I hope this will hep you